# Redirecting to another page on `if` condition

Tags: php, database, pdo

Here after successfully inserting data into database I want user to be redirected to login page but I am not sure what will be the `if` (condition) here.

```php
$stmt = "INSERT INTO users (username,first_name,last_name,email,password) VALUES (:username,:first_name,:last_name,:email,:password,)";
$query = $db->prepare( $stmt );  
$query->execute( array(':username'=>$un,':first_name'=>$fn,':last_name'=>$ln, ':email'=>$em,':password'=>$pswd,));
if (condition) {
    header("Location: login.php");
} else {
    // some error code
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [**`rowCount`**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) to check if there actually *is* inserted a row :

```php
...
if ($query->rowCount() == 1) {
   header("Location: login.php");
} else {
   //something went wrong
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `rowCount();`, which returns the number of rows affected.

```
$count = $query->rowCount();
if ($count > 0) {   
// if the returned number of affected rows is greater than 0 then redirect
header("Location: login.php");
} else {
//some error code
}
```

[PHP Manual: PDOStatement::rowCount](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)